# Search git history for a change in a merge commit

Tags: git, search, history

To search for a string that has been added/removed in git history I can do

```
git log -S'some text'
```

This works great except that it doesn't search through merge commits. How do I get the command to include merge commits in the search?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

it appears that the -m flag gives me the desired result

```
git log -m -S'some text'
```

I found this on another site, if someone could point me in the direction of a man page that includes this flag that would be great. This one doesn't include it http://ftp.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-log.html

Comment: See answer below for info about the -m flag

Answer (score 7):

Since some Git commands are built on top of other ("plumbing") commands they often inherit options from other commands.  I agree that it's annoying not to see those documented in the man pages or in the `--help` output.  In this case, the [git-log](http://ftp.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-log.html) help states:

> The command takes options applicable
>   to the git-rev-list command to control
>   what is shown and how, and options
>   applicable to the git-diff-* commands
>   to control how the changes each commit
>   introduces are shown.

In this case, you'll find the `-m` option under [git-diff-tree](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-diff-tree.html):

```
...
-m
    By default, git-diff-tree --stdin does not show differences 
    for merge commits. With this flag, it shows differences to 
    that commit from all of its parents. See also -c.
...
```

Comment: I had noticed these "plumbing" commands as I was searching for a solution to this problem. Very useful to know that parameters get passed down to these lower commands. I'll know to drill down in future. This seems to be a theme with git, there is a surface layer that you can use to get stuff done, but without knowing the plumbing  layer you can easily become unstuck.

Comment: Be careful with `-m`, quite likely it is **not** what you want. It splits the merge into several "virtual" log entries, one for each parent commit, so files exclusive to a branch will appear as brand new, added files on the other branch diff. To search for changes introduced **in** the merge commit you most likely want `-c` or `--cc`